# Как использовать в C# ChromiumWebBrowser.PrintToPdfAsync

Tags: c#

Моя программа формирует xml документ в котором прописан файл стилей css. Я отображаю его в
ChromiumWebBrowser. Теперь мне нужно сохранить это в pdf. Но у меня не получается, файл pdf не создается, результат выполнения команды `chromeBrowser.PrintToPdfAsync(@"D:\output.pdf"); //= false`. Я не понимаю в чём проблема. Примеры из интернета мне не помогают и их очень мало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на этот вопрос. Корневой каталог вашего XML документа долже иметь стиль block. Например XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<ClassForPrinting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <ListFields>
    <Field>
      <Name>Поле 1</Name>
      <Text>Текст в поле 1</Text>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>Поле 2</Name>
      <Text>Текст в поле 2</Text>
    </Field>
  <ListFiles />
</ClassForPrinting>
```

CSS:

```
ClassForPrinting
{
    display: block; 
}
```

После того как я установил этот стиль у меня начал формироваться PDF файл